# How to animate shapes and Images that draw at onDraw method?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create `myImageView` Custom Control that extends `ImageView`

I need to **animate** everything that draw in `myImageView`.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, getImageMatrix(), paint);
}
```

Comment: are you trying runnable?

Comment: @MHP , no ! , can you give me an example ?

Comment: http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/06/android-graphics-and-animation-part-i/
http://blog.infrared5.com/2011/07/android-graphics-and-animation-part-ii-animation/

Comment: I need An Usefull Answer !